# Access EditText value in another class

Tags: android

Let's say I have the following class

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       //how to access EditText field named "from"  value here?
    }    
}
```

I have a EditText field named "from" on the main layout, I would like to use the value in my onReceive method.

How would that be done?

Answer (score 1):

Create an intent with your action and use sendBroadcast over it like below

```
Intent intent = new Intent("custom_action");
intent.putExtra("key", value);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

and inside your receiver

```
if(intent.getAction().equals("custom_action")){
     String value = intent.getExtras().getString("key");
}
```

Comment: Where would the `Intent intent = new Intent("custom_action");` go? is there a better way of doing this? like creating a static class calling it Pref, loadin all the settings in there and accessing them that way?

Comment: The intent will be used inside activity or from wherever you want to send the data. What is your use case? Because creating a class and saving the data might not help since its a broadcast receiver which can be invoked when your application is not running at all and hence those settings won't be available at that time

Comment: There library is calling that method. Would it better to create a static file with all the settings?